# converting to decimal but without using integer.parseInt() method

Tags: java

So this is my first programming course and I have an assignment to convert a binary number entered by the user to a decimal. And my binary number should be stored in a a string.
And to check that all my digits are 1s and 0s I need to use a method to make sure it's valid and return true if the the number is correct and false otherwise.
So I did a search and saw that everyone was using the `integer.parseInt(String , int radix)` method to convert a binary string to int which worked completely fine, however, the only problem is we didn't take this with my professor so I'm not sure if it's OK and that maybe he wants another way to convert it?

So my question is: how can I write this code in another way that doesn't use this method?.

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
public class Assignment2
{static Scanner stdIn= new Scanner (System.in);
public static void main(String[] args) {

  {String st;
     int converttodecimal;
   
     System.out.println("enter a binary number to convert to decimal: ");
     st = stdIn.next();
   
     while(!validbinary(st)) { 
      
        System.out.println("invalid value, enter a binary number which consists of 1s and 0s only: "); 
        st = stdIn.next(); 
     }
     converttodecimal = Integer.parseInt(st,2);// integer.parseInt(String , int radix);
   
     System.out.println("the equivalent decimal value is: " +converttodecimal ); 
  }
   }//end of main method

  public static boolean validbinary(String st) { 
  for (int i = 0; i < st.length(); i++) {
     if (st.charAt(i) != '0' && st.charAt(i) != '1') {
        return false;
      }
  }
   
  return true;
  }

}//end of class
```

This is the output:

> enter a binary number to convert to decimal:
>
> 110101
>
> the equivalent decimal value is: 53

Thank you in advance I already asked this question else where but I didn't get the answer I wanted.

UPDATE:

I wrote the program again based on your suggestions @akhil_mittal @fabian but if i want to write the converting method in the program itself (not calling the method) how can i do that ?
here's the code:

```
 import java.util.*;
 import java.lang.*;
  public class Assignment2test
  {static Scanner stdIn= new Scanner (System.in);
  public static void main(String[] args) {

  {String st;
     int result;
     
  
     System.out.println("enter a binary number to convert to decimal: ");
     st = stdIn.next();
  
     while(!validbinary(st)) { 
     
        System.out.println("invalid value, enter a binary number which consists of 1s and 0s only: "); 
        st = stdIn.next(); 
     }
     result = convertBinaryToDecimal(st);
     
    
  
           System.out.println("the equivalent decimal value is: " + result ); 

}

 }//end of main method

 public static boolean validbinary(String st) { 
  for (int i = 0; i < st.length(); i++) {
     if (st.charAt(i) != '0' && st.charAt(i) != '1') {
        return false;
     }
  }
  
  return true;
  }

 public static int convertBinaryToDecimal(String st){
    double decimal =0;
    for(int i=0;i<st.length();i++){
        if(st.charAt(i)== '1'){
            decimal = decimal + Math.pow(2,st.length()-1-i);
        }
    }
    return (int) decimal;
}
 }
   //end of class
```

Comment: Integer.parseInt() converts to binary, not decimal.

Comment: @EJP I think we can use it for decimal too. If I am not wrong `String c  = "110";
        int decimalValue = Integer.parseInt(c, 2);
        System.out.println(decimalValue);` then this prints 6 which is String (having binary) to decimal. Am I missing anything?

Comment: as you can see it worked in the output so it really converts from binary to decimal

Comment: No, it's the `System.out.println` step that converted it from binary to decimal, not the `Integer.parseInt`.  EJP is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Do it manually, you can just multiply each digit for the corresponding power of two and sum the results.

Regarding the last part of your question, you can simply use [`java.lang.Math.pow(2,exponent)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow(double,%20double)), there is no specific operator for that if that was what you were wondering.

Comment: Although powers of 2 can be evaluated using `1 << exponent`, so, yes, there IS a specific operator for that case.

Comment: I don't know it he's ready for bitwise operators... better keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

**Binary to decimal Conversion without using Integer.parseInt method**

```
public class BinaryDecimal 
{
    public static int binaryToDecimal(int binary) {
        int decimal = 0;
        for (int power = 1; binary > 0; power *= 2, binary /= 10)
            decimal += power * (binary % 10);       
        return decimal;
    }

    public static void main(String a[]) {
        System.out.println("11 ===> " + binaryToDecimal(11));
        //System.out.println("11 ===> " + binaryToDecimal(Integer.parseInt(a[0]))); //Input from command line
    }
}
```

Comment: soundrain - Check this short snippet solves another way.

Comment: @soundrain - Have you found answer useful?

Answer (score 0):

I have written two methods which use basic computation to convert binary to decimal, one takes `long` and other takes `String`. You can also use them to check the differences in implementation. The method is very simple and easy to understand.

```
    public static int convertBinaryToDecimal(String binary){
        double decimal =0;
        for(int i=0;i<binary.length();i++){
            if(binary.charAt(i)== '1'){
                decimal = decimal + Math.pow(2,binary.length()-1-i);
            }
        }
        return (int) decimal;
    }

    public static int convertBinaryToDecimal(long numberInBinary){
        int decimal = 0;
        int power = 0;
        while(true){
            if(numberInBinary == 0){
                break;
            } else {
                long temp = numberInBinary%10;
                decimal += temp*Math.pow(2, power);
                numberInBinary = numberInBinary/10;
                power++;
            }
        }
        return decimal;
    }

    public static void main(String a[]){
        int binaryNumber = 110011;
        System.out.println(binaryNumber+ " converts to "+convertBinaryToDecimal(binaryNumber));
        String binaryNumberInString = "110011";
        System.out.println(binaryNumber+ " converts to "+convertBinaryToDecimal(binaryNumberInString));
    }
```

If you want to ensure that String only contains `0` and `1` then you can try yourself and let me know if you need any help.

Comment: i kinda understood this but i'm supposed to enter the binary number  as the question says : "write a JAVA program that will repetitively ask the user for a binary number and return its decimal equivalent until an illegal number is entered. " and i think i made sure of that in the method i wrote that it only contains 0s and 1s. also is it strange that my teacher never told us about the "  ...Math.pow(2,binary.length()-1-i); " i'm not really getting it sorry

Comment: @soundrain The method `Math.Pow(2,x)` will return 2 raised to the power x.

Comment: You can replace it with `int pow2(int exponent) {
    return 1 << exponent;
}` as suggested by fabian.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the bit-shift operator to get powers of 2:

```
int pow2(int exponent) {
    return 1 << exponent;
}
```

which should be more efficient than `Math.pow`.

But you could also calculate a binary number like this (example for `0b110101`):

```
((((((1)*2+1)*2+0)*2+1)*2+0)*2+1)
```

i.e. by repeatedly multiplying by 2 and adding the next digit.